# Can I have two different brand GPU to use one on the host and another in the VM via GPU passthrough

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, qemu

I have a RTX 2060 Super, I was reading about to PCI Passthrough on my system https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Setting_up_IOMMU but there's a warning

> Warning: Once you reboot after this procedure, whatever GPU you have configured will no longer be usable on the host until you reverse the manipulation. Make sure the GPU you intend to use on the host is properly configured before doing this - your motherboard should be set to display using the host GPU.

I'm running Catalina on QEMU and I know that even if I successfully setup  my GPU my nvidia card will not work

My question is If I buy something like a Radeon 5700 xt and plugged into my motherboard and make the PCI Passthrough will the host system keep working normal with the nvidia in the virtual guest will use the AMD?

Comment: Not an answer since I am not 100% sure, but don't you get two different PCIe IDs for both cards (same brand or different does not matter?). And you only pass-through one of them. Which means this should work fine.

Comment: The idea is to have two different brand cards

Comment: Then you certainly get two different ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

If your ***only*** reason for buying a second GPU is passthrough, then do yourself a favor and buy a different brand than you already have.

---

Absolutely, you can have two different brand GPUs, one for the Host and one for the Guest (VM).

In fact, that is generally accepted as the easiest way to accomplish GPU passthrough.

In Linux, it allows you to simply blacklist the 2nd card's kernel module and easily isolate it from the host. (Or, perhaps, don't install it's kernel module/driver in the first place?)

Identical cards, on the other hand, both use the same kernel module, so simple blacklisting would disable both.

I *believe* it is possible to do GPU passthrough with identical cards, and I'm sure someone will comment on that, but if you search for information about it you'll quickly find a lot of frustrated people.

(As with anything, this is subject to change as development progresses.)

---

As a side note, I don't know anything about your specific use case, but I would (re)search "catalina on qemu" before spending my money.

Comment: yes I have read many about, currently I have Catalina working on QEMU, and is faster than my real MacBook which is a toy aside my desktop PC, just the graphical interface it seems a bit laggy which make the experience not pleasant but is understandble because the vram of qxl is minimal, so I want to passthrough an AMD GPU which I know is compatible with Catalina